# Load combobox in cakePHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP. I want to load a *combobox* in a form. How can I do it?
Also, I'm using *jQuery* but I don't want to use *prototype* lib for js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by ComboBox? A select-field, an input-field with dropdown (something like autocomplete), .. ?

Answer (score 1):

write in controller

```
$cats = $this->Articles->Categories->find('list');
$this->set(compact('cats'));
```

in view

```
echo $form->select('categories', $cats);
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to conform to the cake conventions because it makes everything easier in the long run. So instead of using `$cats` in the controller, use `$categories` so that in view you can do just `echo $form->input('category_id');` or `echo $form->input('Category');`.

Comment: thanx..i did it using requestAction method...as far as auto complete is concerned i m doing it explicitly through jquery.